# Clean input buffer before fgets

Tags: c++, string, input, buffer, fgets

Today I discovered that `gets(char*)` is deprecated, as `scanf("%s")`,because they take all characters inserted and they can go out from the string memory space. Instead of them we should use `fgets(char*, sizeof char*, stdin)`, but I have a problem in cleaning the input buffer before this function. With `scanf` and gets I use this function:

```
void clean_stdin(void)
{
   int c;
   do {
       c = getchar();
   } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

But if I use it with `fgets` it waits for Enter press before proceed with the program. I realized that it's because `fgets` put the `\n` character in the string (another uncomfortable thing of this function :/ ), but so I don't know how to clean the buffer without waiting for an Enter press. If the user inserts more character than `sizeof *str` they go in the next strings, so there could be a solution to clean the buffer.
Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but if all you want to do is to clean a buffer (with buffer being a `char*`) then what you can probably do is this:

    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

Comment: The simple C++ solution is to use std::cin.clear();.

Comment: None of them function. 
For the first I don't think it can be used to clean the stdin buffer, however I tried it, but it put 0 in the buffer, so the user cannot insert the input from keyboard.
For the second, it seems it doesn't do anything. If the user insert more character than `sizeof*str` it jumps the next string input